# dlib cnn_face_detection_model_v1 Python error

Tags: python, face-detection, dlib

I'm trying to use the dlib (v19.6) Python API to create a CNN face detector using the code:

```
cnn_face_detector = dlib.cnn_face_detection_model_v1('mmod_human_face_detector.dat')
```

However, I get an `ArgumentError` as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ArgumentError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-c2ca0a6e8dff> in <module>()
----> 1 cnn_face_detector = dlib.cnn_face_detection_model_v1('mmod_human_face_detector.dat')

ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    cnn_face_detection_model_v1.__init__(cnn_face_detection_model_v1, str)
did not match C++ signature:
    __init__(_object*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)
```

What might I be doing wrong? Can I not pass the filename of the model file simply as a string?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, using this fresh release and your usage is correct!

This probably means, that you either:

- did something wrong during install

  - installed by `python setup.py install`? That would be correct!
- or: your python-interpreter is using some other dlib-version without your knowledge

Comment: I used `python setup.py install --yes USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS` for installation. I checked that the python interpreter is using the same dlib version. I will try again by doing a clean install.

Answer (score 0):

I had a simmilar issue after `python setup.py install` due to python using an older version of dlib from `/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dlib.so`.

Doing a simple 
`mv /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dlib.so /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dlib_old.so` 
solved it for me.